# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: database "<<database_name>>" does not exist, in the AWS java lambda

Tags: java, postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I am facing the error,
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: database "" does not exist

Java code is deployed in AWS lambda to get connect the postgres database running in RDS.

Code

```
String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://database-1.cfgz85wxhk0z.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/postgres";

Connection connection = null;
try {
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, "database_name", "Password");
    Statement st = connection.createStatement();
    st.execute("select * from <schema>.employee;");
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Are you able to test the connection using something like DBeaver?

Comment: No I haven't checked it. What is DBeaver?

Comment: @Villat, Downloaded the DBeaver tool. Cool its nice tool. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Strange as it sounds, that would indicated that there is no database called `postgres` in that database cluster.

Replace the last part of your JDBC URL with an existing database.

Comment: I have changed it to my database its working. No Idea why it didn't work previously

Answer (score 1):

You should check that your Lambda function is configured to be connected to the same VPC of your RDS instance. Otherwise, they will not be able to communicate.

The [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html) provides more details as well as some tutorials/examples. You can also configure it manually in the AWS Lambda console (in the Configuration pane, under Network, near the bottom of the page).
Finally, AWS has a knowledge base entry on [how do I connect a Lambda function to a dedicated VPC?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-dedicated-vpc/)

Comment: The error message means that the connection to PostgreSQL was successful.

Comment: Yes, I did all the configurations as you suggested before this error.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe You are correct, I missed that. Your answer should be the accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/a75gfw/database_does_not_exist_when_connecting_to/
Followed some suggestions from the above link.
Issue resolved